# How could I separate each JSON object and group them to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

example of req.files from multer.js

```
[
    {
        fieldname: files0,
        originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-23 01-52-30.png',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        destination: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133',
        filename: '1606822252923_Screenshot from 2020-05-23 01-52-30.png',
        path: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133/1606822252923_Screenshot from 2020-05-23 01-52-30.png',
        size: 172092
      },
      {
        fieldname: files0,
        originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-22 08-44-05.png',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        destination: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133',
        filename: '1606822252925_Screenshot from 2020-05-22 08-44-05.png',
        path: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133/1606822252925_Screenshot from 2020-05-22 08-44-05.png',
        size: 440592
      },
      {
        fieldname: files1,
        originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-42.png',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        destination: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133',
        filename: '1606822252930_Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-42.png',
        path: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133/1606822252930_Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-42.png',
        size: 477511
      },
      {
        fieldname: files1,
        originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-36.png',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        destination: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133',
        filename: '1606822252931_Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-36.png',
        path: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133/1606822252931_Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-36.png',
        size: 223362
      },
      {
        fieldname: files1,
        originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-31.png',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        destination: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133',
        filename: '1606822252932_Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-31.png',
        path: 'public/uploads/projects/0a480789-eb14-4fe4-bb89-44aa741efe33/proposals/chma00000133/1606822252932_Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-31.png',
        size: 260419
      }
]
```

I want to dynamically group each JSON objects with their fieldname and store them in an array of objects while using their fieldname number as their array index.

The groups can be between 0 to 9, depending on the user input.

The result I'm hoping for is something like

```
someArr = [

    [
        {
            fieldname: files0
            originalname: somevalue,
            ...
            size: some value
        },
        {
            fieldname: files0,
            originalname: somevalue,
            ...
            size: some value
        },
    ]
        ,
    [
        
        {
            fieldname: files1,
            originalname: somevalue,
            ...
            size: some value
        },
        {
            fieldname: files1,
            originalname: somevalue,
            ...
            size: some value
        },
        {
            fieldname: files1,
            originalname: somevalue,
            ...
            size: some value
        },
    ]
    ...
    
]
```

and if it exists, someArr[9] would return

```
[

    {
        fieldname: files9,
        originalname: somevalue,
        ...
        size: some value
    },
    {
        fieldname: files9,
        originalname: somevalue,
        ...
        size: some value
    },
]
```

What I've tried was first parse integers from fieldnames and reassign them as their values for better sorting with for-loops

```
Object.keys(req.files).forEach((key) => {
  const thisFile = req.files[key];
  const thisFileGroup = parseInt(thisFile.fieldname.match(/\d/g).join(''), 10); 
  // rename fieldname from files0, files1 ... to 0 , 1 ....
  req.files[key].fieldname = thisFileGroup;
});
```

But from here, I can't find where to push this element(thisFile) to, since I cannot predeclare each arrays at the upper scope since they also need to be created dynamically.

Comment: Please accept @mplungjan 's answer. I missed that you need to order by index `0`, `1` etc. Using object is great  for grouping, but the final order will not be organized by the keys alphabetical order.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan checked! I will definitely also keep your solution in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const data = [ 
{ fieldname: 'files0', originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-23 01-52-30.png', },
{ fieldname: 'files0', originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-22 08-44-05.png', },
{ fieldname: 'files1', originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-42.png', },
{ fieldname: 'files1', originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-36.png', },
{ fieldname: 'files1', originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-31.png', }],
arr = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const idx = cur.fieldname.replace("files",""); // get 0, 1
  if (acc[idx]) acc[idx].push(cur); // if already there, just push
  else acc[idx] = [cur];            // otherwise initialise
  return acc;
},[]) 

console.log(arr)
```

NOTE: *The groups can be between 0 to 9, depending on the user input.*

I assume there are no holes since that could result in a sparse array so

```
data = [ 
     { fieldname : 'files0' },
     { fieldname : 'files0' },
     { fieldname : 'files3' },
     { fieldname : 'files3' },
 }
```

would create an array of

```
[
  [ { fieldname : 'files0' }, { fieldname : 'files0' } ],
  null,
  null,
  [ { fieldname : 'files3' }, { fieldname : 'files3' } ],
]
```

Comment: clean and simple!! great answer!! I should look for reduce

Comment: @mplungjan yep Got it! No fieldname `replace` -ing! yey! :P ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No negative assert and hasOwnProperty and object values, Yay!

Comment: @mplungjan you can do `if (!d.fieldname)` but a best practice to follow is hasOwnProperty to iterate enumerables only.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I do not need to do that in my code and you are looping twice, one to reduce and one to ignore the fieldname key of the byFieldName object

Comment: Only problem I see with my code is a null if there is a `filesx` or files0,1,3

Comment: @mplungjan I agree. I get an Object as result, you get an Array. The point is that it does not matters. If you need the entries or values or keys you can use any of the provided methods - while looping your Object - you'll eventually loop it anyways.

Comment: @viviet I think this is the answer you need, by using Objects (as I suggested) you'll loose the index order of groups!

Comment: @mplungjan apologies, I totally missed in OP'squestion the *"order by index"* thing. +1

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan checked, thanks to both Roko C. Buljan and mplungjan, I learned a lot from your comments

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need necessarily an order by index *`files[index]`*

you could in that case [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to **Object**.
Your object will be *grouped* by `fieldname` properties (**not by alphabetical order though**) containing one array with the items having that same property key.
Iterate your object using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) (and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if needed).

```js
const data = [
  { fieldname: "files0", originalname: '0-a'},
  { fieldname: "files0", originalname: '0-b'},
  { fieldname: "files1", originalname: '1-a'},
  { fieldname: "files1", originalname: '1-b'},
  { fieldname: "files1", originalname: '1-c'},
];

const byFieldName = data.reduce((ob, d) => {
  if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(d.fieldname)) ob[d.fieldname] = [];
  ob[d.fieldname].push(d);
  return ob;
}, {});

// console.log(byFieldName); // Uncomment to see how it looks like
console.log( Object.values(byFieldName) );
```

Comment: This code is first reducing and then taking Object values to get rid of the key of the byFieldName  - that is not efficient - it is safer than relying on the digit on the key, but if that is guaranteed, then my code is more efficient

Comment: This will order the final array by the order in which fieldname values are encountered in the input array. You will need to sort the original array by fieldname before reducing using this approach.

Comment: Object or Array - that's data. You @mplungjan can ignore the second console log and treat this answer as if the first is uncommented. You'll loop data anyways if you need to retrieve the values. The better part in having it as structured Object is that you can take - if necessary - directly the entire array by using it's key: `const fn1 = byFieldName["files0"]` when using an array you need to access the deep layers and iterate them as soom `.some()` of the items matches the desired key.

Comment: @pilchard Objects property order is predictable in JavaScript ES2015 - the loop thereafter has no difference in entry.

Comment: I understand that, but try inserting a object with a higher fieldname first in your snippet...

Comment: @pilchard I see what you mean, the group `files1` in such case will be the 0th group. Yes, as I said order is predictable (in the above keys-case specifically) - Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: To fulfill the OPs requirement you can simply sort the data array before reducing `data.sort((a, b) => (a.fieldname.replace('files', '') - b.fieldname.replace('files', '')));`

Comment: pilchard yes I know, but that's unnecessary for this suggestion (which is to *just group them and enjoy the benefits - tough not alphabetically ordered*) additional iterations could be too expensive for something  @mplungjan already solved. - And PS, I missed in the question the OP's need to **order by index**.

Answer (score 1):

I try to not modify your logic to do that.
If there is no `files2`, filesArray[2] will be `undefined`.

```js
// Omit other fields
const req = {
    files: [
        { fieldname: "files0", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-23 01-52-30.png'},
        { fieldname: "files0", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-22 08-44-05.png'},
        { fieldname: "files1", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-42.png'},
        { fieldname: "files1", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-36.png'},
        { fieldname: "files1", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-31.png'},
        { fieldname: "files3", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-42.png'},
        { fieldname: "files3", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-36.png'},
        { fieldname: "files3", originalname: 'Screenshot from 2020-05-30 11-36-31.png'}
    ]
}

let filesArray = []

for (let file of req.files) {
    const thisFileGroup = parseInt(file.fieldname.match(/\d/g).join(''), 10);
    if (!filesArray[thisFileGroup]) {
        filesArray[thisFileGroup] = []
    }
    filesArray[thisFileGroup].push(file)
}

console.log(filesArray[2]) // will be undefined
console.log(filesArray[1]) // will be files1 array
console.log(filesArray)
```